# How to copy files that have been modified within the last day while maintaining folder structure?

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm attempting to copy only data that has changed within the last day from one directory to another. I want to maintain the folder structure when the data is copied over. For example /nas/data/dir1/file.txt changes I would I would want /destination/data/dir1/file.txt created. The closest I've gotten is below.

The main issues I've found with this is that the mtime on a folder is not updated when the contents of a file within is modified. Also I believe that when it is triggered to copy it will copy all files within the folder that was modified.

```
find /NAS/data/dir1 -type d -mtime -1 -exec cp -rt /mnt/dest/dir1 {} +
```

Comment: When a file is modified, the containing folder won't necessarily change. The folder would only change when files are added or removed. Why not `find -type f`?

Comment: Your tentative command is somewhat strange an in contradiction with what you write. To be clear: what you want is to copy only recently modified files, preserving the directory structure, but you don’t want to copy all files and all subdirectories of a directory containing one modified file, right?

Comment: So if I used type -f it would only copy the files and not the folder they're within. There  are many subdir under dir1 and even more below that. So what I'm trying to achieve is if say /nas/data/dir1/subdir1/4302019/file.txt changes I want to copy that folder and the directory structure but not necessarily all the files/directories in subdir1. Sorry If this seems convoluted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your find looks for directories (-type d) and not for files (-type f). Because you only want to copy some files in a deep directory structure, i think you can't do it with a simple find ... -exec (because cp needs the directory structure in the destination). Here is a sample script (with comments), that you can use:

```
# create a reftime (for the last 24h)
((reftime=$(date '+%s')-(24*60*60)))
# create a reffile for that time in /var/tmp (or any other place)
reffile=/var/tmp/reffile.$$.tmp
touch --date=@${reftime} ${reffile}

# find all files (in srcbase), that was changed in the last 24h - that means 
# now all files that are newer then our reffile, and copy to destbase...
srcbase=/NAS/data/dir1
destbase=/mnt/dest/dir1
# for all of these files we need the directory names (because we need the structure for copy)
chgfiles=/var/tmp/chgfile.$$.tmp
find ${srcbase} -type f -newer $reffile 2>/dev/null | sort -u >${chgfiles}

# now you have a file list that you must cp (or print or whatever)
cat ${chgfiles} | while read f ; do
  dest=$(dirname $(echo "$f" | sed -e "s#${srcbase}#${destbase}#"))
  echo "copy file $f to destination $dest ..."
  # create directory structures if not exist
  mkdir -p "${dest}"
  # and finaly cp the file
  cp "${f}" "${dest}/"
done

# clear all tmp files
rm ${reffile} ${chgfiles}
```

Comment: Because you later clarify that you also want to copy all files in the same directory of the changed file, you must extract the dirname of ${f} before copy and copy after that the whole content of this directory (with * if you only want to copy none hided files or with * and .* for all files). And additional questions: what about files in subdirectories? If you also want to copy, then you can use -R for the cp command

Comment: For clarification I just want to copy the files that had changed not necessarily all the files in the directory when a file has changed. So the find command above would grab only the files newer but I'm not understanding where we're finding the directory structure to create if its missing. Sorry I'm pretty new and its somewhat tough to parse what you've written. I'm very grateful though.

Comment: find always brings you the complete structure starts from your startpoint. if you use find as described in the code, you start with an absolut path (srcbase=/NAS/data/dir1), so all results had an absolut path (i.e. /NAS/data/dir1/subdir_a/subdir_b/anotherpath/file.txt) because you change the srcbase to destbase (done by sed) your result is a file in your destination structure (including all subdirectories). mkdir -p creates this (if not exist) or do nothing (if the directory exists)